# Write from one fixed canvas to another floating

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, transform

I have an imageCanvas with it's Transform matrix

```
Image = new image();
image.src = //stuff; 
imageContext.drawImage(Image, 0, 0);
var t = imageContext.currentTransform;
```

that is drawn on another canvas

```
context.drawImage(imageCanvas, 0, 0);
```

on which I draw lines

```
context.moveTo(mousePos.X, mousePos.Y);
context.lineTo(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y);
context.stroke();
```

I save my lines into a vector of objects 'lines'.
I would like to join the two layers into the 'Image', but this function works only for traslation but not for rotation and scaling.

```
var saveCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var saveContext = saveCanvas.getContext('2d');

saveCanvas.width = Image.width;
saveCanvas.height = Image.height;

saveContext.drawImage(Image,0,0);

saveContext.save();
var t = imageContext.currentTransform;
saveContext.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-t.e,-t.f);

for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    saveContext.beginPath();
    saveContext.moveTo(lines[i].from.X, lines[i].from.Y);
    saveContext.lineTo(lines[i].to.X, lines[i].to.Y);
    saveContext.stroke();
}
saveContext.restore();

Image.src = saveCanvas.toDataURL();
```

how can I modify the arguments of 'setTransform' to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the rest of the transforms attributes.

```
var t = imageContext.currentTransform;
saveContext.setTransform(
   t.a,
   t.b,
   t.c,
   t.d,
  -t.e,
  -t.f);
```

Comment: nope, but i solved just now.

var m = [[t.a,t.c,t.e],[t.b,t.d,t.f],[0,0,1]];
m = math.inv(m);
saveContext.setTransform(m[0][0],m[1][0],m[0][1],m[1][1],m[0][2],m[1][2]);

Comment: @Simone It would have helped to know you wanted the inverse matrix. You can also get the inverse matrix by doing `t.inverse()`.